# Runtime exec on linux

Tags: java, linux, runtime, terminal, exec

I want to run a java program (jar) in an other terminal on Linux.
Here is my code :

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

public class Launcher
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(6000);
                Process p;

                if( System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("win") )
                {   
                    BufferedWriter bw;
                    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start java -Xms512M -Xmx512M -jar craftbukkit.jar");
                    bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
                    bw.write(launcher + "\r\n");
                    bw.flush();
                }
                else
                {   
                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(launcher);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

On Windows there is no problem, the jar is launched in an other console.
But on Linux the jar is launched in background and not in an other terminal.

Thx for help!

Comment: And what is "other terminal" anyway? /dev/ttyN? Many linux installations run without GUI.

Comment: Hmm. Depends on the big picture. Java is ment to be platform independent. Well you may have a reason that you need something platform dependent. In that case I would actually do the platform dependent stuff separate like in a little shell wrapper and call that to make it configurable(one uses Konsole, another Gnome terminal, another eterm or xterm...). But if I wanted to keep it the Java way, that is platformindependent, I'd try to make the "terminal" in Java: Pipe stderr and stdin to some Java "window".

Answer (score 1):

This is going to depend on the Linux distro and the user's chosen desktop environment.

You need to figure out which console / terminal emulator you are using, look at its command-line options and find the one that allows you to specify a command to be run.  For example:

- `gnome-terminal -e "some command"` runs `some command` in a new console, closing the console when the command exits.
- `gnome-terminal -e "bash -c \"some command" ; sleep 10\"` runs `some command` in a new console, waiting for 10 seconds before closing.

Other console / terminal emulators will probably do this differently ...

The final step is to use `Runtime.exec(...)` or `ProcessBuilder` and friends to assemble the composite command.

Comment: ... and don't forget that desktop environment may be not there at all.